# Apply classes to sub elements of components

Tags: angular

I'm using ng-bootstrap, however the question can be generalized.

Suppose I have a component with this piece of html:

```
<ngb-alert type="danger" class="py-2 mt-3">This is an alert</ngb-alert>
```

When it's rendered, I get:

```
<ngb-alert _ngcontent-c3="" class="py-2 mt-3" type="danger" ng-reflect-type="danger">
    <div role="alert" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
        <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"}-->
        <button aria-label="Close" class="close" type="button">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        This is an alert
    </div>
</ngb-alert>
```

As you can see, of course the classes `py-2 mt-3` are applied to the `<nbg-alert>` element, while I'd like to apply them on the `<div>` element.

Since usually one doesn't have access to third party components implementation, how may I achieve to apply the classes to the sub element? Is that something that could be done with css?

Answer (score 1):

You will just have to add inside your ngb-alert component an Input() attribute.
Then when you call the component you pass the value to that input. From within the component class you can use that use to do whatever you want. Below is a basic example of how you can perform that action.

```
<div role="alert" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible {{myClass}}">
    <button aria-label="Close" class="close" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
    This is an alert
</div>


import { Input } from '@angular/core';
export class ngbAlertComponent {
    @Input() myClass : string;
}


<ngb-alert type="danger" myClass="{{'py-2 mt-3'}}">This is an alert</ngb-alert>
```

**EDIT 1**

As you are using a module. I made a fork and update the alert component. You should be able to add you custom classes.
Here is the repo link npm install https://github.com/ulrichdohou/ng-bootstrap

You can install with yarn this way `yarn add git+https://git@github.com/ulrichdohou/ng-bootstrap.git`

Not sure how you can do it using `npm`
Now you can just use the component this way

```
<ngb-alert type="danger" customClass="{{'py-2 mt-3'}}">This is an alert</ngb-alert>
```

**EDIT 2**

You can also perform this with pure css. Thats a suggestion I got from the github repo of this module

```
<ngb-alert class="myclass"></ngb-alert>
ngb-alert.myclass > div { your-css-here }
```

Comment: Thank you, that is for sure the preferred way on my own components. But what about third party libraries? In this example ngb-alert is a component of the official library ng-bootstrap. Should I really make my custom version of their source code to achieve that?

Comment: I think so. I will for the repo and make a pull request. I will add an option to allow user to add custom class. I will update my answer with the repo link and the pull request one too. But for now I suggest you create your own this way. Or you can use pure javascript to add the class you want

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, even though I thought there may have been some other solution (maybe with css?) to apply classes to third party component without having to mess with their code. Thank you anyway!